# Emailer - Embedding html source code into email

Tags: html, css, nodemailer

When I embed my html source code into email, the CDN's won't work (Bootstrap and FontAwesome that I've used) for the receiver. Any idea why the CDN's wont work? I have used inline styling everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are not the same as html pages. Many email clients cannot process link for css files. You have to include the necessary css rules in a style tag in the head or even better, transform the css into inline style properties onto the html elements.

No worries, this online tool can do that for you: http://automattic.github.io/juice/

Here is a great article on emails and css: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Edit: I just saw, you used inline styles. In this case, you don't need CDN include. All the styling is on the element.
Could you post a bit of your code?

Comment: I just discovered CDNs do not work with HTML emails. Leaving that aside, can you help me with my background and background-color doesn't work? I write them just like all the other style properties.. within the element.